Installing berkeleydb in Windows: FileNotFoundError: 'db/include\\db.h'
OS: Windows 64
Python: Anaconda3 Python 3.11.5
enter image description here
I have the C compiler Visual Studio 2022 installed.
Thank you for your help.
I basically tried all the previous relevant posts without solving this error.
But the same error happened.
